# Finding winners of races in SQL

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with results for users, participating in different races.
The one with the highest performance score in each race is the winner of each race.
So in the example below Alice has 0 wins, Bob has 1 and Chris has 2 wins.

What I need, is to be able to calculate for a given user how many wins he/she has across all races he/she participated in, and also another number of how many podium results (1st second or 3rd place).

Is this even possible with SQL alone? I'm using MySQL

P.S. I have no idea why the table isn't rendered correctly, it looks perfect in the preview, so if anyone can fix it, it's much appreciated.

| RaceID | UserID | Performance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | 90 |
| 1 | Bob | 100 |
| 2 | Alice | 100 |
| 2 | Bob | 90 |
| 2 | Chris | 110 |
| 3 | Alice | 90 |
| 3 | Bob | 80 |
| 3 | Chris | 150 |

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() in CTE and aggregate in outer query. From the other side - what if 2 users have the same maximal performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to get the rows of wins for each user and sum them:

```
SELECT t1.UserID,
       SUM(NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tablename t2 WHERE t2.RaceID = t1.RaceID AND t2.Performance > t1.Performance)) wins
FROM tablename t1
GROUP BY t1.UserID
```

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ you can do it with MAX() window function and aggregation:

```
SELECT UserID, 
       SUM(Performance = max_performance) wins
FROM (
  SELECT *, MAX(Performance) OVER (PARTITION BY RaceID) max_performance
  FROM tablename
) t
GROUP BY UserID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=de810ab8ca58dd2a98329b01e77f1a11).

Comment: Thank you @forpas - good solution and very nice to add the demo as well